# Can we install fluentbit as a binary in ubuntu?

Tags: fluent-bit

So we can execute it from cli like: `$ fluent-bit -h`.

Was following the documentation, but it only installs as a service.
https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/linux/ubuntu#install-fluent-bit

```
Using the following apt-get command you are able now to install the latest fluent-bit:
sudo apt-get install fluent-bit

Now the following step is to instruct systemd to enable the service:
sudo systemctl start fluent-bit
```

Answer (score 0):

What's exactly your issue? You can run the same binary run by the service.
Or you can install it wherever you want from the sources.